# how to make primary key and current timestamp column in a mysql table in sync

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table `tableA` with schema,

```
create table tableA( 
id bigint auto_increment primary key, 
data varchar(25), 
updated_at datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null 
);
```

while creating a new record only `data` column will be provided with value from the client side. id, updated_at will be automatically added by the MySQL server.

At first I assumed that for all the rows, id and updated_at column will be in sync like

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | data  |     updated_at      |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | ajith | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 |
|  2 | sql   | 2020-01-07 00:00:01 |
|  3 | query | 2020-01-07 00:00:02 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

as you can see from the above table *if id of row x > id of row y then updated_at of row x is also >= updated_at of row y*

but after some testing, I found out that its not always the case, it could even be like

```
+----+-------+---------------------+
| id | data  |     updated_at      |
+----+-------+---------------------+
|  1 | ajith | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 |
|  2 | sql   | 2020-01-07 00:00:02 |
|  3 | query | 2020-01-07 00:00:01 |
+----+-------+---------------------+
```

is there any way to make this 2 columns in sync while creating new record?

Comment: Are you single inserting(1 insert at a time) or bulk inserting(1 insert many values or 1 insert ..select)?

Comment: Doesn't CURRENT_TIMESTAMP return the same timestamp every time within a statement?

Comment: @P.Salmon Its always bulk inserting

Comment: @jarlh *Doesn't CURRENT_TIMESTAMP return the same timestamp every time within a statement?* Impossible. CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the time of statement's execution start. So it is the same for all calls in the statement.

Comment: *is there any way to make this 2 columns in sync while creating new record?* 1) Why this is so critical for you? 2) Read [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Comment: @Akina 1) It is critical for me because I am building a REST API where if pagination is handled with primary key(id), then query is 7x faster than handling with both updated_at and id.

Comment: Maybe simply there is no proper index? by `(updated_at, id)`...

Comment: @Akina No, i have index for updated_at but not mentioned it in the question because i thought it is irrelevant

Comment: I mean one composite index, not 2 separate ones.